# Ajax .load() function not working

Tags: html, ajax, load

**.load() only works on files coming from a server, so it will work later as I'm going to put this on a server**

**Edit: This code works on firefox but not on chrome**

I've been trying to use ajax to load a webpage after selecting an option but the script doesn't even seem to load

here's the script + html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="DaVinciRace.css" />
 <title> Da Vinci Race 2014-2015 </title>
 
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
 
</head>

<body style="background:#f2f2f2;">

<div id="logo">
 <img src="Resources\DVRLogo.png"/>
 <!-- <p class="text">Da Vinci Race</p> -->
</div>

<div id="options" style="background:#0c0c0c; float:right;">
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="chronometre" ></div>
 </div>
</div>



<div id="DVRChrono">

</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#options").on("click", ".chronometre", function() {
   $( "#DVRChrono" ).load( "Chronometre.html" );
  })
 });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

the document "Chronometre.html" is in the same folder as this html page

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but can't for the life of me figure out what it is

Comment: Is there an error in the browser console?  Does the JavaScript execute at all?  Is the network request made?  What is the server's response?  How, specifically, does this fail?

Comment: there's no error in the console, there's 5 request and jQuery is one of them and the status say "304 not modified".   As for how it fails, nothing happens when I hit the button

Comment: You should enclosed the js code in `$(function(){ .......... });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>
(function($){    
  $("#options").on("click", ".chronometre", function() {
    $( "#DVRChrono" ).load( "Chronometre.html" );
  })
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: that didn't work either, and the network still says "304 not modified"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't adding a click handler:

```
$("#options").on("click", ".chronometre", function() {
    // code
});
```

Because it executes *before* the `#options` element exists on the page.  The code is executing without error, the jQuery selector simply isn't finding anything.  So there are no elements to which a handler can be attached.

You can fix this either by moving the code to the end of the page or by wrapping it in the `document.ready` handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("#options").on("click", ".chronometre", function() {
        $( "#DVRChrono" ).load( "Chronometre.html" );
    });
});
```

**Additionally**, your `script` tags are broken.  Each tag should have either a `src` *or* content, but not both.  Separate them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // your code
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried this code and $(document).ready(function(){ --code-- }); and both of those didn't change anything, weird

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: Did you also try splitting up the `script` tags?  If you have an updated example which still doesn't work as expected, please show it.  Also, please debug the code to determine where specifically it fails.  You've been assuming that "the `.load()` function isn't working" when in fact your code was never calling that function in the first place.

Comment: I separated them and it didn't work either, I'll update that, as for debugging, I'm using notepad++ and I don't know of any debug fonctions for it

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: Is Notepad++ *executing* your code?  I would think the code would be executing in a *web browser*, no?  Debugging means examining the runtime behavior of the code, so you'd need to examine it in the web browser.  Use something like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to examine the behavior of the code.

Comment: I did that and in the network tab I get "304 not modified" for JQuery, as for the console, it's just empty

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: 304 isn't an error.  jQuery is loading just fine.  If the code which is currently shown in your question is the "updated" version then the same problem described in my answer still exists.  The code is executing without error, it's simply not attaching a click handler to any elements.  The `#options` element *doesn't exist* when the code executes.  You need to either move the code to after that element (so that it does exist) or wrap the code in the `document.ready` handler as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: According to the code in your question, you did not try them.  Nobody here can help with code you're not showing us.  If you have an updated version, please include it in the question.  "It doesn't work" isn't a meaningful problem description.  Show the code you're using, step through that code in a debugger, and provide information.  I can't get this information myself because I can't actually see your screen from here.

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: The structure of the code itself works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ogrk28oq/  In what way does it not work for you?  When you debug this, does the `.on()` function get executed?  Does it find the `#options` element?  Is the `.chronometre` element visible and clickable?  When you click it, does the click handler execute?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  I can't stress enough that "it doesn't work" doesn't describe the problem.

Comment: this code works, and in the console, the only thing written is "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", nothing about .on(), #options